# Как отменить приведение угловых кавычек?

Tags: wordpress

Пишу `<>` получаю `&lt;&gt;`. А необходим именно первый вариант.

```
add_filter( 'run_wptexturize', '__return_false' );  
remove_filter('the_title', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('comment_text', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('list_cats', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('single_post_title', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('comment_author', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('term_name', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('link_name', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('link_description', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('link_notes', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('bloginfo', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('wp_title', 'wptexturize');
remove_filter('widget_title', 'wptexturize');
```

Привел последнюю версию кода которым попытался это поправить. Безуспешно. 
Прошу совета как исправить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о контенте, то можно использовать такой код в `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'action_save_post', 10, 3 );
function action_save_post( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $content = str_replace('&lt;','<',$content);
    $content = str_replace('&gt;','>',$content);

    remove_action( 'save_post', 'action_save_post' );
    wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_ID, 'post_content' => $content ) );
    add_action( 'save_post', 'action_save_post', 10, 3 );
}
```

Хук работает при сохранении поста. Исправляем контент, потом обновляем пост. Чтобы избежать зацикливания (wp_update_post вызывает хук save_post), сначала удаляем хук, потом обновляем пост, и снова восстанавливаем хук.

Тестовая страница [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/so643508/).

Так она выглядит в базе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: решение не работает, но за попытку спасибо

Comment: Исправил ответ, протестировал.

Comment: Я благодарен, что ты потратил на решение моего вопроса время. Я вижу по коду что оно, очевидно, обязано работать. Но, увы, у меня не работает. Думаю это связано с тем, что я удалил что-то не уместное из formatting.php. Воспользуюсь твоим решением когда откачу core